# Box plot, given intervals and not discrete values

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am investigating the income of a region and am given intervals,

e.g. 0 to 99,000 kr (first over interval)
100,000 to 199,000 (second interval) etc, 
 and the last interval is ''over 600,000 kr''

I'd like to make a box plot to get an idea of the skew of the data and just because I have done so for other indicators I am investigating e.g. education.

I could use Mid interval values which would mean that my lowest value is 49500 kr, and so on. This could be my minimum value for the box plot, but what about the maximum value, since I can't find the MIV for the upper limit of ''over 600,000 kr''?

Please help, I am confused

Comment: Boxplots are not really an option unless you can get meaningful values for the 'five number summary': min, lower quartile, median, upper quartile, maximum.

Comment: Ah okay, Is there a good alternative to a box plot?